# Update SQL Server two statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

```
UPDATE ADDRESS 
SET ADDRESS.LATITUDE = b.latitude,
    ADDRESS.LONGITUDE= b.LONGITUDE
FROM POSTAL_CODE_LOOKUP b
WHERE ADDRESS.postal_cd = b.POSTALCODE
  AND (address.LATITUDE != b.LATITUDE OR address.LONGITUDE !=b.LONGITUDE)

 11:20:23  [BEGIN - 2454 row(s), 0.437 secs]  Command processed
 11:20:23  [BEGIN - 2454 row(s), 0.437 secs]  Command processed
... 2 statement(s) executed, 4908 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.874/0.000 sec  [2 successful, 0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

After executing the update I run the SQL below and get 2454 records.

```
select 
    a1.POSTAL_CD, b.POSTALCODE, 
    a1.LATITUDE, b.LATITUDE, 
    a1.LONGITUDE, b.LONGITUDE
from
    ADDRESS a1, POSTAL_CODE_LOOKUP b
where 
    a1.postal_cd = b.postalcode
    and (a1.LATITUDE != b.LATITUDE or a1.LONGITUDE != b.LONGITUDE);
```

Yes I have committed, and the records haven't changed. I don't understand why the update is being read as 2 statements. I don't understand why it's not updating.

How should I be writing this update statement?

Comment: Perhaps `Address` has an `UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: You should not be using old-style joins anymore: [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Strange question, but are you sure you've tagged the question correctly? Those output messages don't resemble [tag:sql-server] ones that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Your ADDRESS table must have Update trigger, that's why there is a second statement about 2454 rows.

The amount updated is just 2454 rows, the same number You select after.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple rows in your join for one postal code i think

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script to update the Address table .

```
UPDATE a 
SET    a.LATITUDE = b.latitude,
       a.LONGITUDE= b.LONGITUDE
FROM [ADDRESS] a
 JOIN POSTAL_CODE_LOOKUP b
        ON a.postal_cd = b.POSTALCODE
WHERE (a.LATITUDE != b.LATITUDE or a.LONGITUDE !=b.LONGITUDE)
```